# Neovim no me deja escribir los archivos

Tags: vim

apenas empiezo con vim y bueno ahora nvim no me deja guardar ningun archivo
:wq
y lanza esto "E382: No se pudo escribir, la opción "buftype" está activa "
como lo soluciono?